# Umbraco add items dynamically

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a problem where I cannot figure out how to solve.

Lets say i have a company with products. I want to be able to add new products, delete products and edit current products.

I also want to list these projects on a product page.

I know how to add pages and so on. But does this require that i need to create a single page for each product? And then get all childpages information?

I am greatful for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the products. If you want to have a product detail page, then it makes sense to have a page for each product.

On the other hand, if you want to just list the products and not have a page for each one, you could use something like [Archetype](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/archetype/), or [Nested Content](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/).

It's also worth bearing in mind that if this is going to be an e-commerce site, there are a number of excellent options available that you could use for product management etc. You should investigate [uCommerce](http://www.ucommerce.net), [Tea Commerce](https://teacommerce.net) and [Merchello](https://merchello.com) for example, to see if they offer the functionality that you require without needed to write too much yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Work through the beginners' tutorial 
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/creating-basic-site/

The articles parent and child model can be used for what you need (instead of "Articles Main" you'd have "Product Listing" and "Article Item" would be "Product"). If you don't need a specific page for each product just don't assign a template to the product nodes.